# C++ program using <bitset> running pretty slow

Tags: c++, performance

```
int main(){
  double one, zero, bias;
  double max = -2.0;
  string plaintext, ciphertext, firstFourStr, lastFourStr;
  bitset<16> V;
  bitset<16> base("0000110000001011");
  bitset<16> targetKey;
  for(int k=0; k<16; k++){
    ifstream plaintexts ("plaintexts.txt");
    ifstream ciphertexts ("ciphertext07.txt");
    bitset<12> tmpBs(k);
    bitset<16> add(tmpBs.to_string()+"0000");
    bitset<16> guessedKey1(add^base);
    for(int j=0; j<16; j++){
      bitset<4> tmpBs2(j);
      bitset<16> add2(tmpBs2.to_string()+"000000000000");
      bitset<16> guessedKey(guessedKey1^add2);
      one = zero = 0.0;
      for(int i=0; i<20000; i++){
        getline(plaintexts, plaintext);
        getline(ciphertexts, ciphertext);
        bitset<16> pTxt(plaintext);
        bitset<16> cTxt(ciphertext);
        V = guessedKey^cTxt;
        bitset<4> firstFour((V.to_string()).substr(0,4));
        bitset<4> secondFour((V.to_string()).substr(4,4));
        bitset<4> thirdFour((V.to_string()).substr(8,4));
        bitset<4> lastFour((V.to_string()).substr(12,4));
        bitset<16> U(sBoxInverse(firstFour)+sBoxInverse(secondFour)+sBoxInverse(thirdFour)+sBoxInverse(lastFour));
        if((U[2]^U[6]^U[10]^U[14]^pTxt[4]^pTxt[7]^pTxt[12]^pTxt[15]) == 0) zero++;
        else one++;
      }
      plaintexts.close();
      ciphertexts.close();
      bias = zero/(zero+one)-0.5;
      if(bias < 0) bias *= -1;
      if(max <= bias){
        max = bias;
        targetKey = guessedKey;
      }
      cout << bias << endl;
    }
  }
  cout << targetKey << ": " << max << endl;
}
```

I was doing my cryptography assignment and this is the program I wrote to get the key. But it runs pretty slow. I tried to replace some lines of code with simpler ones to check if operations like to_string() or set() caused the problem but it seems that they have nothing to do with the problem. So what causes the program to run slow?

Comment: If you are on windows, you can use Visual Studio Profile Analyzer (or something like that, don't recall how it's called). If you are on linux you can use valgrind with callgrind. There are profilers and will show you where your code spends most time.

Comment: my feeling is that the IO here is the most taxing here. I mean you have `16 x 16 x 20.000 x 2 = 10.240.000` calls to getline.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the thing which is slowest in that code is not the `std::bitset`s, but rather the extensive (and unnecessary) use of `std::string`s to manipulate them. For example:

```
 bitset<16> add2(tmpBs2.to_string()+"000000000000");
```

requires creating a `std::string` from a bitset, making a new `std::string` by concatenating that with a constant C string, and then reinterpreting the result as a `std::bitset`.

You'd be much better off manipulating the `std::bitset`s as unsigned integers and using bitwise operators and shifts.